# To parse SQL with regex, excluding quoted literals

Tags: php, mysql, regex, parsing

For my DBAL I need to parse supplied SQL [mysql dialect, specifically] string to find all the placeholders.

But, of course, I don't want to parse any placeholder-like combinations, that occasionally may occur inside of quoted literals - either single quoted or double quoted or backtick-quoted.

Say, it could be

```
SELECT amount as `Amount: boxes` FROM t WHERE q='howdy?' and a='I\'m OK' and category=?
```

Where only last question mark is the only actual placeholder

Given multitude of escaping rules, some of them depends on the current DB settings (`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`, `ANSI_QUOTES` and such), which can turn the above query into

```
SELECT amount as "Amount:boxes" FROM t WHERE q='howdy?' and a='I''m OK' and category=?
```

I doubt the mission is possible at all.

However, I still hope it can be done and may be someone even have a solution at hand.

Comment: might be too big for the task but have you considered http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser over regex?

Comment: I held it as a last resort. Not a full SQL parser like this one of course, but the same principle. However, it seems NikiC handled it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general pattern you're looking for is `/string(*SKIP)(*F)|\?/` where `string` is a regular expression matching strings. I'm not intimately familiar with SQL string syntax. Some suggestions:

- Single quotes with backslash escape: `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'`
- Single quotes with quote duplication escape: `'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'`

E.g. a full regex for single quotes, double quotes and backticks with backslash and duplication escaping could look like this:

```
/(?:
    '[^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|'')[^'\\]*)*'
  | "[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^"\\]*)*"
  | `[^`\\]*(?:(?:\\.|``)[^`\\]*)*`
 )(*SKIP)(*F)| \?
/x
```

Match that with `preg_match_all` or `preg_replace_callback`, depending on what it is you want.

Note: To avoid additional escaping put the regex in a NOWDOC string.

Comment: @AmalMurali I've added double quotes and backticks

Comment: I saw the update, and +1'd already :) Here's a working demo: https://eval.in/116177

Comment: Ugh. Thank you, Nikita (and @Amal for the demo). I have to admit I scarcely can decipher the pattern (here goes a confused smiley) but it works! Good answer always makes you learn more and this one is of the kind.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Beware that this operation would need to be performed with full awareness of the character encoding used on the database connection.  Sure, in PHP "PCRE" patterns can be [modified](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to use `PCRE_UTF8` mode, but that's still only one of the many possible character encodings... and since PHP doesn't offer perl-compatible regex in its multibyte extension... sadly I don't see an easy generic solution here.  Perhaps your safeMySQL could force UTF-8 on the connection and transcode in PHP if required?

Comment: @eggyal I would rather make all identifiers explicitly whitelisted

Comment: @YourCommonSense: My point here doesn't have anything to do with identifiers... I'm saying that this regex, intended to ignore placeholder patterns that appear within string literals etc, is not safe for use in all connection encodings.

Comment: @eggyal for the hardcoded query I doubt there is any danger

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Perhaps no risk of exploitable attack, but it still gives rise to buggy behaviour if one is using a multibyte character encoding.  Suppose one uses GBK and provides the command string `"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE foo = '\xbf\x27?' OR bar = ? OR qux = '\xbf\x27?'"` - the pattern in this answer, performed unaware that the connection is GBK, would match on the third byte of both the strings against which `foo` and `qux` are compared and *would not* match against the `?` placeholder for `bar`!